# error while downloading pdf from Pubmed within python3

Tags: python-3.x, pubmed

I ma trying to download PubMed pdf from within python using fetch pdf
here is the code

```
mkr5="18368049"
os.system('python3 fetch_pdfs.py -pmids$mkr5')
```

I get this error

```
fetch_pdfs.py: error: argument -pmids: expected one argument
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use the value in `mkr5` as the argument for `-pmids`, you could use an f-string:

```
mkr5="18368049"
os.system(f'python3 fetch_pdfs.py -pmids {mkr5}')
```